# Assistente Virtual

Tags: python, python-3.x, scrapy, python-kivy, chatbot

Boa tarde companheiros, como vão?

Então sou razoavelmente novo nesse ambiente de desenvolvimento e já programei em python há algum tempo atrás. Estou com uma ideia de projeto no qual envolve em criar uma especie de assistente virtual (uma versão de criança de uma Siri ou Amazon Alexa). Realizei algumas pesquisas, vi alguns vídeos e juntei algumas bibliotecas e frameworks que acredito me ajudarem nesse projeto. Contudo, gostaria de saber se essas bibliotecas não iram conflitar de alguma forma e se esse é o melhor caminho que posso tomar.

Outra dúvida que tenho é sobre UI em python. A melhor escolha hoje é Kivy? E será possível que eu consiga desenvolver esse código, com essas bibliotecas com python kivy para criar um Android app?

As bibliotecas/frameworks são essas:

Reconhecimento de voz - https://pypi.org/project/SpeechRecognition/

Sintetizador de voz - https://pypi.org/project/pyttsx3/

Chat Bot - https://chatterbot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

Busca (Mineração) na Internet - https://scrapy.org

Interface gráfica + Cross-Plataform (Android?) - https://kivy.org/#home // http://excript.com/python/kivy.html

Aceito dicas, opiniões e xingamentos. Desde já agradeço a compreensão de todos!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estou trabalhando em algo similar nesse momento, no entanto não conseguia dinamizar a minha aplicação utilizando o speech_recognition do python, como alternativa encontrei algumas outras bibliotecas/programas que podem te ajudar se não estiver satisfeito com o desempenho do speech_recog, elas são snowboy e picovoice fazem tarefas semelhantes porém com a vantagem de serem offline e muito mais rápidas, o único adendo que te faço sobre elas é que possuem muito pouco material e são (pelo menos para mim) muito difíceis de serem instaladas foram dias de pesquisa para solucionar todos os erros que acontecem até elas começarem a funcionar.

Como você quer utilizar no Android o picovoice já vem com uma demo "pronta" para você testar.

Aqui está o link delas:

https://snowboy.kitt.ai/

https://picovoice.ai/

Answer (score 0):

Em Python temos um framework incrível para construir aplicativos nativos que podem ser empacotados para essas diversas plataformas!
Portanto, se você quer desenvolver para Android, iOS, Windows, Linux ou Mac OS utilizando nosso querido Python, o Kivy é uma ótima aposta!
Outras vantagens do Kivy: ele é totalmente grátis, já está em suas versões estáveis e é muito bem documentado.
Toda essas bibliotecas que você listou são muito boas.
Esses links talvez te ajude 
https://www.treinaweb.com.br/blog/criando-um-chatbot-com-python/

e de uma olhada nessas outras bibliotecas:
Biblioteca Speech Recognition, 
Sintetização de Fala com Pyttsx3